# Some trouble with recursive Function

Tags: c, recursion

I tried to use recursive function to create my power function.The Problem was given as:"Write a Power function, which can work with a base(natural) and a power(integer)". But there is a trouble when user "give me" negative power. Please find a mistake. All printf functions aren't needed(except printf's in main).

```
#include <stdio.h>

int Power(int power, float base)
{
    printf("%f\n", base);
    printf("POWER%d\n", power);
    if (power == 0)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        if (power < 0)
        {
            return Power(power *= -1, 1 / base);
        }
        else
        {
            if (power == 1)
            {
                printf("%f\n", base);
                // printf("POWER%d\n",power);
                return base;
            }
            else
            { //printf("%f\n",base);
                //printf("POWER%d\n",power);
                return base * Power(power - 1, base);
            }
        }
    }
}
int main()
{
    int a; //power
    printf("Enter a power: ");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    printf("Enter a base: ");
    float b; //base
    scanf("%f", &b);
    if (b == 0)
        printf("0");
    else
    {
        float y = Power(a, b);
        printf("%f", y);
    }
}
```

Comment: `int Power(int power, float base)` Why return an `int`?

Comment: Re-read the assignment. The base is a Natural (integer greater than zero) while the exponent (power) is a Real. This is not the correct approach and your function signature does not match the assignment.

Comment: Please explain why you use `power *= -1` instead of `-power` or `0 - power`? Also, why not just use `pow` from `math.h`? Recursive functions are often just the plain wrong way of solving a problem. Don't get me wrong, I understand it's an exercise, but one I think most people learn the wrong lesson.

Comment: For the sanity of clarity, you may do well to look at your code closely and realize just how many places `else` isn't required due to a hard-return in the prior block. Removing the redundancies and cleaning that up, your function becomes about 1/4th the code here. I.e. [somethin like this](https://pastebin.com/TBaDjKpu)

Comment: @Cheatah  its like a task.

Comment: ^^^^ aka an assignment to learn recursion. Pretty sure punting to `pow` is not on the agenda .

Comment: @dxiv Ty, You are right, stupid mistake

Comment: It may be a task, but if you don't learn that recursive functions should be avoided whenever possible, it's not teaching you the right lesson.

Comment: @Cheatah The very point of the lesson is how recursion works; whether/when/where it is appropriate to use is another issue entirely. You'd be hard pressed to find a simpler lesson to learn the mechanics of how recursion works than this one. (though I suppose a Sigma may be even simpler).

Comment: @Cheatah There is a lot of context missing. For all we know, this could be the first step towards discussing tail recursion, and how to rewrite the power function to use it.

Comment: @JackLilhammers Well, about *"0^0, which is NaN"*, it's a bit [more complicated than that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_to_the_power_of_zero).

Comment: @Bob__ the next time my suggestion will be to "handle 0^0, which is a bit more complicated than that" :D Anyway, you're right. I'll edit my comment

Comment: As a side note, I'd suggest you clean that function a little and handle 0^-n, which should output division by zero

Answer (score 0):

Try this in negative:

```
if (power<0)
        {
            return 1/Power(-power, base);
        }
```

Comment: Comments are right float instead int ( def power function)